# Rails 5 - heroku puma - random timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I've recently switch from `unicorn` to `puma`.

As expected, the performances are better !

However, there is something happening that I dont understand.

All the time, my API is handling thing well for the 95 percentile and below.

But, for no apparent reason, from time to time, I've got some strange `Timeout` from heroku on the 99 percentile (over 30seconds of waiting time)

[image]

Here in the screenshot, the big rectangles are timeout on the 99th percentile...

So I've check me log reader, and some `random routes` are `randomly in timeout`, so this is not a question of API performance.

---

**Also !**

I have the `rack timeout gem`
with the following configuration :

```
# config/initializers/rack_timeout.rb
Rack::Timeout.service_timeout = 25  # seconds
```

but the timeout are **never** raised here, only in H12 on heroku (so **after** 30sec)

---

**This happens from the moment I started using `Puma`**

Any idea ?

```
API configuration :
  ruby 2.5.1
  rails 5.1.4

PUMA configuration
  gem version 3.11.4
  3 workers
  5 threads
  preload_app!
```

Comment: One option is a slow clients with a very large response. This will circumvent the Rack::Timeout middleware since the response will be passed on to the server and the issue would be a network concern. Does it happen with passenger or iodine? If so, it might be the client.